# 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid bloktype: ' in /public_html/app/Mage.php:594

Tags: javascript, php, magento

Customers have problems with checking out in my webshop. In the log files there are two errors.

The following error in the exeption log file:

```
2015-09-25T00:14:07+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Ongeldig bloktype: ' in /home/snellens/public_html/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /home/snellens/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Ongeldig blokty...')
#1 /home/snellens/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('', Array)
#2 /home/snellens/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('', '.cart')
#3 /home/snellens/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('', 'checkout.cart')
#4 /home/snellens/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/snellens/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/snellens/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/snellens/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/snellens/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(159): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#9 /home/snellens/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_CartController->indexAction()
#10 /home/snellens/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#11 /home/snellens/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /home/snellens/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /home/snellens/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /home/snellens/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
2015-09-25T07:12:21+00:00
```

The following error in the system log file:

```
ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php'  in /public_html/app/design/frontend/default/snellens/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml on line 49
2015-09-25T07:07:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1
2015-09-25T07:07:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1
2015-09-25T07:07:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1
2015-09-25T07:07:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1
2015-09-25T07:07:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1
2015-09-25T07:07:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1
2015-09-25T07:07:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1
2015-09-25T07:07:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1
2015-09-25T07:07:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1
2015-09-25T07:07:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1
2015-09-25T07:07:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1
2015-09-25T07:07:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1
2015-09-25T07:07:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): 1
```

And this is my config file `etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date/>
        </install>
        <resources>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host>localhost</host>
                    <username/>
                    <password/>
                    <dbname>magento</dbname>
                    <model>mysql4</model>
                    <initStatements>SET NAMES utf8</initStatements>
                    <type>pdo_mysql</type>
                    <active>0</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
            <default_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </default_write>
            <default_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </default_read>
            <core_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mage_Core</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </core_setup>
            <core_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_write</use>
                </connection>
            </core_write>
            <core_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_read</use>
                </connection>
            </core_read>
        </resources>
        <resource>
            <connection>
                <types>
                    <pdo_mysql>
                        <adapter>Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql</adapter>
                        <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Type_Db_Pdo_Mysql</class>
                        <compatibleMode>1</compatibleMode>
                    </pdo_mysql>
                </types>
            </connection>
        </resource>
        <models>
            <varien>
                <class>Varien</class>
            </varien>
            <core>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>core_resource</resourceModel>
            </core>
            <core_resource>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource</class>
                <deprecatedNode>core_mysql4</deprecatedNode>
                <entities>
                    <config_data>
                        <table>core_config_data</table>
                    </config_data>
                    <website>
                        <table>core_website</table>
                    </website>
                    <store>
                        <table>core_store</table>
                    </store>
                    <resource>
                        <table>core_resource</table>
                    </resource>
                    <cache>
                        <table>core_cache</table>
                    </cache>
                    <cache_tag>
                        <table>core_cache_tag</table>
                    </cache_tag>
                    <cache_option>
                        <table>core_cache_option</table>
                    </cache_option>
                </entities>
            </core_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
    <default>
        <system>
            <filesystem>
                <base>{{root_dir}}</base>
                <app>{{root_dir}}/app</app>
                <code>{{app_dir}}/code</code>
                <design>{{app_dir}}/design</design>
                <locale>{{app_dir}}/locale</locale>
                <etc>{{app_dir}}/etc</etc>
                <media>{{root_dir}}/media</media>
                <upload>{{root_dir}}/media/upload</upload>
                <skin>{{root_dir}}/skin</skin>
                <var>{{var_dir}}</var>
                <cache>{{var_dir}}/cache</cache>
                <session>{{var_dir}}/session</session>
                <tmp>{{var_dir}}/tmp</tmp>
                <pear>{{var_dir}}/pear</pear>
                <export>{{var_dir}}/export</export>
            </filesystem>
        </system>
        <general>
            <locale>
                <code>en_US</code>
                <timezone>America/Los_Angeles</timezone>
            </locale>
        </general>
    </default>
    <varien>
        <class>Varien</class>
    </varien>
</config>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's rather hard to tell without the relevant source code.

Comment: I'm willing to bet there is some custom code in `app/mage.php` since it throws an exception with the message in Dutch.

Comment: The code on line 594 in app/Mage.php is:

 public static function throwException($message, $messageStorage = null)
    {
        if ($messageStorage && ($storage = self::getSingleton($messageStorage))) {
            $storage->addError($message);
        }
        throw new Mage_Core_Exception($message);
    }